# How to persist Firebase User Auth on React Native/

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now. I built my app using Expo, and a big part of it is to allow the app to be used while the user is offline. The way this is supposed to work is whenever I open the app up, I am taken to the `Login` screen. From here, a `useEffect` hook will determine if the user is logged in or not, and if it is, it will redirect to the `Home` page. This works when the user is online, but for some reason whenever I build the app and I close it on my iPhone (fully close it), and then reopen with airplane mode on and wi-fi disconnected, I'm stuck on the `Login` screen not being able to do anything as I have no connection.

---

This is my **firebase.js**:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// import { getAuth, initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  getReactNativePersistence,
  initializeAuth,
} from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import { getFirestore, enableIndexedDbPersistence } from "firebase/firestore";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

And this is my `useEffect` on the `Login` screen:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("USER: " + user + " " + user?.email);
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 14):

with help from the below link I've fixed this issue while replying to my own gitHub issued raised for this:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7152

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7164

**The steps to fix this are:**

**Versions**

"expo": "~48.0.6",

"react": "18.2.0",

**npm i firebase**
("firebase": "^9.19.0")

**npm i @react-native-async-storage/async-storage**
("@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11")

**npm i @react-native-firebase/auth**
("@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.4.0")

**Create a firebaseConfig.js file**

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getReactNativePersistence,
  initializeAuth,
} from "firebase/auth/react-native";

export const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  // enter your firebase project details
  apiKey: "..........",
  authDomain: "..........",
  projectId: "..........",
  storageBucket: "..........",
  messagingSenderId: "..........",
  appId: "..........",
  measurementId: ".........."
});

export const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

**Create App.js**

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import AppMain from './AppMain';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppMain />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
});

export default App;
```

**Create AppMain.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Dimensions, TextInput, ActivityIndicator, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { auth } from './firebaseConfig';

import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
console.log(width, height);

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("USER IS STILL LOGGED IN: " , user);
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      }
    });
  }, [user]);


  const handleLogin = () => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log('User logged in successfully:',  userCredential);
        setUser(userCredential);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User logged out successfully:');
        setUser(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  };

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        />
        <Button title="Login" onPress={handleLogin} />
        <Text style={styles.text} type='black' >{'\nYou Are Logged Out.'}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  if (user) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.text,{fontWeight: 'bold'}]}>{"USER STILL LOGGED IN: \n\n"}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{'email: ' + user?.email}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{'uid: ' + user?.uid}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{"\nAccess Token:\n\n" + user?.accessToken}</Text>
        <Button title="Logout" onPress={handleLogout} />
      </View>
    );
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  text: {
    color:'#000',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal:20
  }
});
```

**The following steps should keep the user logging in after refreshing the app. It also handles the sign in and sign out functions. This issue was bugging me for a while :).**